# I'm seeing Chinese letters after converting UTF-16 to UTF-8

Tags: php, arrays, csv, utf-8, utf-16

I have a UTF-16 encoded .CSV file. The field delimiter is a comma (,) and string delimiter is double quotes ("). Changing the encoding outside of PHP is not an option. I need to turn it into an associative array with PHP. But I can't seem to get it to recognize that UTF-16 encoding.

Here is my file contents for **numbers.csv**:

```
"Phone number"
"+1 55500718"
"+1 55551919"
```

I have successfully uploaded the file like this (*using Laravel framework*)

```
$file = $request->file('numbers-file');
$filename = $file->getPathName();
```

I also have a custom function csvToAssocArray() that turns it into an associative array. *I am using mb_convert_encoding to convert UTF-16 to UTF-8.*

```
function csvToAssocArray($filename) {
    $csvAsArray = array_map(function($data) {
        return str_getcsv(mb_convert_encoding($data, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16'), ",");
    }, file($filename));

    $header = array_shift($csvAsArray);

    $csv = array();

    foreach ($csvAsArray as $row) {
        $csv[] = array_combine($header, $row);
    }

    return $csv;
}
```

But the end result of ***print_r(csvToAssocArray($filename))*** looks like this:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "∀倀栀漀渀攀 渀甀洀戀攀爀∀" => "+1 55500718"
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "∀倀栀漀渀攀 渀甀洀戀攀爀∀" => "+1 55551919"
  ]
]
```

Comment: Mayby the source is some other encoding? This code looks good to do a quick test what the original encoding could be: http://php.net/manual/de/function.mb-convert-encoding.php#97902

Comment: Here is the result https://pastebin.com/dpwsUbBH

Comment: maybe your file is `UTF-16LE`?

Comment: When I tried LE then it was the other way around - the numbers were now chinese and the headers were correct.

Comment: @Liga would you try going to this website, upload the csv, set it to utf-16 to utf-8, and see if the result is the same. If you get the same chinese characters then you know the issue isn't your code, and rather the issue is the file isn't really utf-16 encoded. https://www.fileformat.info/convert/text/utf2utf.htm

Comment: I would like to see the actual file uploaded here or somewhere that volunteers can access/play with it.